# Error of euler's method with variable step

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, initial-value-problems

Let $a= t^0   \lt   t^1   \lt … \lt   t^N  =b$ a random division of $[a,b]$ space where  $h_n = t^{n+1}  -  t^n$  for $n=0,1,…,N-1$.

We consider the initial value problem
$$        y'(t)=f(t,y(t))\text{ for } a \le  t  \le  b \ \&\  y(a)= y_0 
$$

Function $f \in ( C[a,b]×R )$ and satisfies the Lipschitz condition with constant $L>0$ for $a \le  t  \le  b$

In addition, $M=\max|y''(t)|$ & $h=\max h_n $ for $0  \le  n  \le  N-1$

Show that $| ε_n |  \le   M {h\over2L}  [ e^{L(b-a)}  -1]$

We define  $ε_n =y( t^n )- y^n$  the error of Euler's method with variable step  $h_n$  and by applying this method to the problem we conclude to this:

\begin{align}
| ε_{n+1} |  
&\le  (1+ h_n L)| ε_n | + h_n  {h\over2} M  
\\
&\le  M {h\over2}  \Bigl[ h_n +(1+ h_n L) h_{n-1} +(1+ h_n L)(1+ h_{n-1} L) h_{n-2} +
\\&\qquad\qquad…+(1+ h_n L)(1+ h_{n-1} L)\cdots(1+ h_1 L) h_0 \Bigr]  
\\
&\le  M {h\over2}  \Bigl[ h_n  +  e^{L(t^{n+1}-t^n)} ( t^n - t^{n-1} )+ e^{L(t^{n+1}-t^{n-1})} ( t^{n-1} - t^{n-2} )+
\\&\qquad\qquad…+ e^{L(t^{n+1}-t^1)} ( t^1 - t^0 )\Bigr]  
\\
&\le  M {h\over2}  \Bigl[ h_n  +  \int_{t^{n-1}}^{t^n}    e^{L(t^{n+1}-s)}  ds  +  \int_{t^{n-2}}^{t^{n-1}}    e^{L(t^{n+1}-s)}  ds +
\\&\qquad\qquad…+ \int_{t^0}^{t^1}   e^{L(t^{n+1}-s)}  ds\Bigr] 
\\
&= M {h\over2}   \Bigl[ h_n  + \int_{t^0}^{t^n}    e^{L(t^{n+1}-s)}  ds\Bigr]
\end{align}

At this point I have been stuck because I don't know how to get rid of the ' $h_n$ ' I would appreciate any help ..How could I continue in order to show this? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I have to admit that you've been very polite but it was my first attempt to write in mathjax and certainly I didn't nail it... Although I can't see something unreadable here... so except "my formula salad" if you had something else to add about the problem, you 'd help me a lot! thanks

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1696107/115115 for the idea for the standard treatment of this problem.

Comment: @kaithkolesidou - you don't need to split every single item into separate `$ $` pairs. It really looks better and is a LOT easier to read if you just do an entire fomula instead of bits and pieces. For example: `$$a=t^0 \lt t^1\lt \ldots \lt t^N =b$$` gives $$a=t^0 \lt t^1\lt \ldots \lt t^N =b$$ instead of "a=$t^0$ $\lt$ $t^1$ $\lt$ ......$\lt$ $t^N$ =b"

Comment: @LutzL the ex. gives certain steps we should follow in order to achieve the final inequality, and the point i've stopped it's the last given step.. if i calculate the integral then i conclude to the above inequality BUT the hn is stil there...

Comment: @PaulSinclair thank you for pointing it out.. I didn't know that I could have used the" $ $" without separating items.. It 's certainly easier and quicker that way..

Comment: A well-formatted formula may be a pain to enter, but it can be very much worth the effort. For example, that long formula in your original post was such mess that I really did not want to try and parse it, but with LutzL's edit, it is much easier to follow, and thus you get more people who are willing to read it and may give useful answers (as LutzL has already provided). Another useful tip: anytime you see a formula and want to know how they did it, right-click on the formula and select "Show Math As >> TeX Commands".

Comment: Or you can view the source code of the post using the "edit"link/button.

Answer (score 1):

Just use
$$
h_n=e^{L(t^{n+1}-t^{n+1})}·(t^{n+1}-t^n)
\le \int_{t^n}^{t^{n+1}}e^{L(t^{n+1}-s)}
$$
to get to
$$
\int_{t^0}^{t^{n+1}}e^{L(t^{n+1}-s)}ds=\frac1L\left(e^{L(t^{n+1}-t^0)}-1\right).
$$

Comment: yeeeees you're right... thank you very very much for your help and for your time!!